# Pick a single value of $\ln z$ for every $z \in \mathbb C^\star$, validating the logarithm's usual algebraic properties

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

The logarithm of a nonzero complex number is not a single complex number, but rather an equivalence class modulo $2\pi i$. Is there a (possibly wildly discontinuous, non-measurable, requiring the axiom of choice, name your favorite evil) way to pick a representative of each class in such a way that the following properties always hold?

$$\ln(a_1 \cdots a_n) = \ln a_1 + \dots + \ln a_n, \qquad \qquad \qquad a \ln b = \ln b^a$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\ln(1\cdot 1)=2\ln(1)$, we get $\ln(1)=0$. But then from $\ln((-1)\cdot(-1)=2\ln(-1)$, we get that also $\ln(-1)=0$, which is not among the allowed choices..

Comment: Whoa, I was looking for a disproof in crazy places, but I had to look no further than the real negative axis.